# Change Fontcolor of chapter using titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I would like to color my chapter title and number in red using titlesec but somehow cant get the color on the title itself to work. since its part of a big, nested thesis I dont have MWE, just the code to define the chapter. there must be the error somewhere...
the design looks like this:

[image]

```
\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{red}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{red}

\newcommand\mychapformat[1]{%
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter} }%
    {\textcolor{red}}%
  {\vspace{-3px}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
        \rule[-5pt]{1.5pt}{2.3cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
        \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\mychapformat}%
  [\phantomsection]
```

Merci A

Comment: What color should the title be?

Comment: By the way, it's not a good idea to use `titlesec` along with `scrbook`.

Comment: @egreg the color should be red. if you know a better way to achieve the design, I gladly use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that it is not recommended to use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. But you have mentioned a big template (maybe based on package `cleanthesis`?). So it does not make sense for me to give a suggestion without `titlesec`.

You could use:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{red}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{red}
\colorlet{ctcolorchaptertext}{red}

\newcommand\mychapformat[1]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}\color{ctcolorchaptertext}}%
  {\vspace{-3px}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
      \rule[-5pt]{1.5pt}{2.3cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
      \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\mychapformat}%

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{red}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{red}
\colorlet{ctcolorchaptertext}{red}

\newcommand\mychapformat[1]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-3em\relax}{\raggedright#1}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
  {\usekomafont{chapter}}%
  {\vspace{-3px}\raggedleft{%
    {\color{ctcolorchapterline}%
      \rule[-5pt]{1.5pt}{2.3cm}}\quad%
    {\color{ctcolorchapternum}
      \fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    }%
  }%
  {-2.1em}%
  {\mychapformat}%
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\color{ctcolorchaptertext}}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result for numbered chapters is the same as above, but the ToC title is colored red, too.

Comment: Merci, the colorlet{ctcolorchaptertext}{red} was my missing link...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
\colorlet{ctcolorchapterline}{red}
\colorlet{ctcolorchapternum}{red}

\titleformat{\chapter}%
[display]%
{{\usekomafont{chapter}\color{red}}%
{\vspace{-3px}\raggedleft{{\color{ctcolorchapterline}\rule[-5pt]{1.5pt}%{2.3cm}}\quad        {\color{ctcolorchapternum}\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}}}%
{-2.1em}%
{}%
[]
```