Changing color of section
I am completely new to LaTeX. I want to change the format of my sections, subsections, etc: I simply want to change each of their colours using the titlesec package. Can someone provide me with a simple example of how this is done?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you maybe provide some sample code that shows how you are currently formatting the section titles?

I am not. I don't know how. I just want to change the color. Thank you!

Please try to come up with something even if it does not work. You say that you would like to use the titlesec package. So you should be able to make a first step. Please help us help you and show some code.

What about this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/430467/47927 or this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225097/47927 ? Maybe it can already help you.
